# 'Activity Detection API' Get current activity only once

Tags: android, google-play-services, activity-recognition

I have successfully set up activity recognition tracking but it requires using an interval for activity updates.

```
ActivityRecognition.ActivityRecognitionApi.requestActivityUpdates(
            googleApiClient,
            updateInterval,
            activityRecognitionPendingIntent)
            .setResultCallback(this);
```

Is there a way to avoid this and ask for the activies when needed?

Eg: ActivityRecognition.getCurrentActivities();?

Comment: As I have read in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/ActivityRecognitionApi), interval is required. I suggest that you use larger values to have fewer activity detections while improving battery life. For example, use a value of 60000 or 1 minute so you can check your app less frequently. `ActivityRecognition.ActivityRecognitionApi.requestActivityUpdates(googleApiClient, 60000, activityRecognitionPendingIntent);`

Answer (score 0):

Need to have more information to fully answer your question but, here's a checklist of things to verify:

1.have you made the GoogleApiClient.Builder api call? Assume so given the parameter googleApiClient used in your code sample.

2. Does the class your are calling from implement GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, ResultCallback
3. Does your ActivityRecognitionPendingIntent method instantiate a new Intent and call PendingIntent.getService using it?
4. does your pendingIntent.getService call use the PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be notified of activity changes, but only when it is different from your current activity, do the following:

1. Capture the initial activity and store the [enum](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/DetectedActivity) in a persistable manner (static variable, SharedPreferences, etc).
2. If you get the next update, check if it is the same [enum](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/DetectedActivity) as the last one.  If not, report the new activity.  If it is the same, just pass through.
3. Set the interval to how often you want the updates to occur.  A longer delay will greatly improve power savings.